# Select as in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do something like this:

```
select username, userid, 'user' as new_column  from  users_table.
```

The columns of the table can be selected using sqlalchemy as follows:

```
query = select([users_table.c.username, users_table.c.userid])
```

How do I do the select `x` as `col_x` to the query in sqlalchemy?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do aliases of column names without entering in raw SQL. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to do union of this query with another query which has a column with name 'new_column'

Comment: This question shows up as a top result for ["Rename Column In Query SQLAlchemy" on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rename+column+in+query+sqlalchemy) but does not actually ask that question. The question seems to have more to with creating a literal column than renaming an existing column.

The top voted answer, answers the Google query but not the best guess of the authors question.

All that combined with none of the links to docs working anymore and changed APIs I think this is better archived / closed to prevent any more confusion.

Answer (score 84):

Use the `label(...)` function: `users_table.c.userid.label('foo')`

i.e.,

```
query = select([users_table.c.username, users_table.c.userid.label('foo')])
```

evaluates to:

```
SELECT username, userid as foo FROM users;
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe literal_column?

```
query = select([users_table.c.username, users_table.c.userid, literal_column("user", type_=Unicode).label('new_column')])
```

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column

Edit:
 actually I should have said "literal":

```
query = select([users_table.c.username, users_table.c.userid, literal("user", type_=Unicode).label('new_column')])
```

Comment: literal_column() is more appropriate here unless the user wants a bind parameter to be generated.   so your first answer is correct.

Answer (score -2):

See the `alias()` in the docs here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=alias#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Alias

Comment: [`alias()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html?highlight=alias#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.alias) as far as I can tell is for aliasing `FROM` clauses like tables, subqueries, etc. (eg: `FROM foo as bar`). For SELECT clauses like  columns, aggregates, etc using [.label('new_name')](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html?highlight=label#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.label) as mentioned above is the answer