# SQLAlchemy: Building query with custom field and value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to convert following SQL query to SQLAlchemy analog?

```
SELECT 'custom_value' AS `custom_field`, f.`bar` FROM `Foo` f
```

'Foo' model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(String)
```

Comment: What is `custom_field` and where it is from?

Comment: It's just custom, "handmade" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at second example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576573/344141

In short - use `literal("custom_value", type_=Unicode).label('custom_field')`, so your query will look like this:

`session.query(literal("custom_value", type_=Unicode).label('custom_field'), Foo.bar)`

Comment: How to import the function literal?

Answer (score -4):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(String)


engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db = Session()

# Results
qu = select([Foo.custom_field.label('custom_value'), Foo.bar])

results = db.query(qu).all()
```

[Note - I'm not near a version of Python, but believe this to be correct from my memory

Comment: It seems wrong. AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'custom_field'

Comment: I'm sorry that it is wrong. It was however stated that I am not near a copy of Python... therefore cannot guarantee correctness..